Webcomic about a muscular/strong woman who fell to earth/came from alt dimension
I'm trying to track down a webcomic I was reading circa 2019-2021 and I think this one had its origins on DeviantArt.  I don't remember the exact nature of the story as to how she wound up on earth but wound up in someones backyard (not sure if she was alien or from another dimensions) but the key points that I recall are

She was escaping from something
There was a bit of the muscle girl/strong woman + the geek trope
She used simplified language but wasn't dumb
The art was better than entry level and depicted who are with tanned colour skin, strong and fairly tall
She was followed by a sister, also tanned but more lightly built and did not have the speech pattern
I seem to recall a name like Bambam or similiar

Any takers? It is NOT Down To Earth on Webtoon.

Possibly The Adventures of Zona? The geek found himself in her world, not the other way round, but she did have a less muscular sister.

Not that one; setting was current day Earth (or very near future)
